# Customized sorting based on selected text in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, split

Background:
I have an Excel sheet with four columns (title, URL, status, type).
The table is a mix of text from various users who use different separators in the column title:

- hyphen (surface-air-temperature)
- underscore (latent_heat_flux)
- plus and blank (+land surface elevation+)
- point and blank (,Total cloud cover)

Problem:
The in-built customized sorting works up to a certain point. Unfortunately it does not target the ending of each entry (examples above).

Desired solution:
I would like to select a specific text as criteria for the sorting.

**Before:**
[image]

**After:**
[image]

Possible approach:
I have been thinking about splitting the rows. Unfortunately I cannot specify/customize the splitting. Would it be possible to write a script that allows "cut" the text at a specified point (e.g. that *-mean-sea-level-pressure* is separated from the rest and displayed in another column)?
CLIM-PRO-CMIP-SINGLE-XXXX-M-HISTORICAL-*mean-sea-level-pressure*
Another obstacle might be that different separators have been used.

**Before splitting:**
[image]

**After splitting:**
[image]

Comment: Hi, Could you please provide an image of samples before and after. You can do this by hand and the sample doesn't need to be more than say 2 or 3 rows. Take a screenshot and upload it, please.

Comment: Hope that now it is clearer. :)

Comment: Yes, this is by far clearer, many thanks. This is certainly achievable, but you need 2 things: **1** A full list of all possible separators and **2** a full list of all possible sorting keywords (e.g. "mean sea level pressure", "version 5.1cds" and so on). These lists can grow/shrink as needed, but do you have such defined lists?

Comment: Well, not at hand but I can generate them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function

```
Function EXTRACT_SORT_KEYWORDS(INPUT_TEXT As String) As String
  
  Application.Volatile
  
  Dim vSeparators As Variant
  Dim vKeywords As Variant
  Dim v As Variant
  
  EXTRACT_SORT_KEYWORDS = ""
  If Len(INPUT_TEXT) = 0 Then Exit Function
  
  ' Add more separators here
  vSeparators = Array(" ", ";", ",", "-", "_")
  
  ' Add more keywords here. Note the line continuations
  vKeywords = Array("mean sea level pressure", _
                    "surface air temperature", _
                    "latent heat flux", _
                    "land surface elevation", _
                    "land surface elevation", _
                    "total cloud cover", _
                    "cloud cover", _
                    "mean precipitation flux" _
              )

  For Each v In vSeparators
    If v <> " " And InStr(1, INPUT_TEXT, v, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
      INPUT_TEXT = Replace(INPUT_TEXT, v, " ")
    End If
  Next v
  
  INPUT_TEXT = Trim$(INPUT_TEXT)
  
  
  For Each v In vKeywords
    If InStr(1, INPUT_TEXT, v, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
      EXTRACT_SORT_KEYWORDS = v
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next v
  
End Function
```

As your data grows, it is not a good idea to have many user defined functions in you sheets as they will slow down your application considerably. A better solution is to have code that generates this column dynamically, performs the sort and then delete the column.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Sorry for my late reply, I was trying to get it run. Unfortunately it produces an error message (#Name) and I could not find out why.

Comment: I can think of 2 reasons why this might happen: Either you have a typo in the formula (please check the name you entered for the function) OR you have not copied the code into the right module. Make sure you copy it into a regular vba module (i.e. not  a class module). Hope that works for you